# Cyclic Subgroups of $\Bbb Z_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I just started learning some basic group theory. The definition of cyclic groups I read is as follow:

A group $G$ is a cyclic group if there exists some element $g\in G$ so that $G=\{g^k\,|\,k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

The material I read gives an example of $G=\Bbb{Z}_6$, and then its cyclic subgroup is $\langle 2 \rangle=\{0,2,4\}$. But according to the definition, only 2 and 4 would be in $\langle 2 \rangle$ because $2=2^1$ and $4=2^2$. Why is 0 in there but not 1 (since $1=2^0$ ) ?

Comment: In your example $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$, what's the group operation?

Comment: @Daniel Hast It wasn't specified, I thought I was multiplication cuz I saw $g^k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing additive and multiplicative notation.   So $2^0=0\cdot 2=0$.  $2^1=2$, and $2^2=2+2=4$.

It's an easy mistake to make. Especially considering that $\Bbb Z_6$ is also a ring, so has addition and multiplication.

The identity of the additive group $\Bbb Z_6$ is $0$.  It has to be in your subgroup.

Comment: I see now, if I'm talking about $(\Bbb Z_6, +)$, then $g^k=g+g+\cdots+g$ not $g\cdot g\cdot g \cdots g$. Still have to jump out of the circle of basic arithmetic. Thank you.

Comment: Good catch.   That's it.